# bitnami.keycloak Cannot login to the admin console after installation

Tags: keycloak, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I just installed [bitnami/keycloak](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/keycloak/10.1.6) via the helm chart version, 10.1.6.

But when I try to open the admin console on "**/admin/master/console/**", it's stuck on a loading screen. I inspected the console and it seems like it's calling an init endpoint on "**login-status-iframe.html/init?client_id=...**" which keeps returning 403 Forbidden.

I read a number of helps online, most of which were suggesting that I change the "Web Origins" configuration on the master realm but I can't even log in, in the first place.

I can't tell whether it's an issue with keycloak itself. Or with the bitnami chart.

I've tried a number of configurations, to no avail. I've attached a screenshot of my current values file for the chart.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel Sarpong, did you manage to solve this. I am stuck with the same for a few days now.

Comment: If I change the KEYCLOAK_PRODUCTION value to false I can access the admin console and log in. I havent figured out how to make it work with KEYCLOAK_PRODUCTION set to true

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue, using the Codecentric chart.